# How To Create a Private NPM Repository and publish the NPM Package

Tags: npm

Can someone explain the step by step process to create the NPM Package and Publish the Package to Private Repository.

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://www.nodejitsu.com/ they have private NPM repo